# Segment mailchimp list based on activation link clicked in email

Tags: mailchimp

In my Codeignitor website, I have a registration form.. Earlier my developer added mailchimp API to collect users details in mailchimp who register and it's working fine (as soon as someone registers their details get saved both in mailchimp and in my site's backend).

After registration users receive an email as well with a link to activate their account on my website.. Now I want to segment my mailchimp list based on who activated their account and who didn't.. (want to move users in separate lists based on who clicked the activation link).. Currently, as soon as someone registers their details get saved in one list whether they activate their account or not..

Please note that the email users are receiving on signup is coming from Codeignitor site itself (not from mailchimp, it's not the confirmation mail from mailchimp).

Please let me know if this is possible and how can it be accomplished.. If you can provide any reference link that would be very helpful..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution for this,

**Step 1:** Create a Group/Segment as Radio button(prefered) with two options'Activated Users' and 'Not-activated Users'

**Step 2:** Add all users who signing up to the site into the 'Not-activated Users' segment.

**Step 3:** After a user clicks the activation link, you need to write custom code after the activation process to add that user into the 'Activated Users' segment.

**Step 4:** Remove the user from 'Not-activated Users' segment.

Please give me some feed back…